# react - add icons to header inside component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, jsx

i am currently trying to solve a react problem.
i want to be able to add icons to a container called SalesChannels.
here is the code to the salesChannels page: (JSX)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PageContent from 'components/PageContent';
import IBox from 'components/IBox';

export default class SalesChannelsPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            rows: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <PageContent header="Salgskanaler">
                <IBox title="Salgskanaler">

                </IBox>
            </PageContent>
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, i have added a component called IBox. this should be reusable
it looks like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import IBoxTools from './IBoxTools'

export default class IBox extends Component {
    render() {
         return(
            <div className="ibox">
                <div className="ibox-title">
                    {this.props.title}

                //this is where the icon should be rendered in the dom

                </div>
                <div className="ibox-content">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>    
        );

    }
}
```

i have also created another component called IBoxTools - this contains the actual icon / "i" tag:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class IBoxTools extends Component {
    render() {
        let icon;

        if(this.props.icon) {
            icon = (
                <a title={this.props.title}>
                    <i onClick={() => this.iconClicked()} className={`pull-right ${this.props.icon}`}></i>
                </a>
            );
        }

        return icon;
    }

    iconClicked() {
        console.log('icon clicked')
    }
}
```

So what i am trying to do is add multible icons to the SalesChannels page, inside the IBox tag, without making the IBox component dependent on it.

I hope you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass components or arrays of components in props just like `children`

```
<IBox 
  title="Salgskanaler"
  icons={[
    <IBoxTools key="icon1" icon="foo" />, 
    <IBoxTools key="icon2" icon="bar" />
  ]}
>
  {/* normal children here */}
</IBox>
```

Then inside `IBox` you write `{ this.props.icons }` which will render the icons (or whatever else) if you pass it in.. otherwise will display nothing if the prop is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a condition if you don't want to display the icon every time. If I understand what you're attempting to do ...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import IBoxTools from './IBoxTools'

export default class IBox extends Component {
    render() {
         return(
            <div className="ibox">
                <div className="ibox-title">
                    {this.props.title}

                //this is where the icon should be rendered in the dom
               {(condition) ? <IBoxTools /> : ""}

                </div>
                <div className="ibox-content">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>    
        );

    }
}
```

Or if you need to do it multiple times, like you said, then I would use underscore.js or something like it that has a map function.

```
{_.map(icons, function(icon) {
    return (
        <IBoxTools />
    )
})}
```

Or some combination of the two.

Comment: regular JavaScript has a `map` function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map